# Using Google Cloud Storage Files with Jupyter Notebook on Cloud Compute

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a machine learning project and I just set up a google cloud account.

I have a VM instance up and running and Jupyter is working. I placed a couple of file folders on Google Cloud Storage assuming I could connect it to my VM and use the files in a Jupyter notebook running Python 3.

I have not been able to find a way to access the files in storage from my virtual machine. Someone help please!?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage is an object storage service, you can access it from any VM using `https`. What do you mean 'assuming I could connect it to my VM'? It isn't a file store so there is no 'connecting'.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. I incorrectly assumed that google cloud storage was a file store. Should I store on files on my Virtual Machine then? What file store would you recommend for me to use to be accessed by the VM?

Comment: GCS has python APIs. What happens when you try to use them?

Comment: With Cloud Storage you can [list objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects), [download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects), [rename, copy and move](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects), etc. If what you're trying to do is to modify the files interactively you will not be able to do it. One option is to download them, modify them and then upload them again. There is a [Python library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) that you can use for these.

Answer (score 2):

To access cloud storage from a VM, it needs the VM to have been created with the API access. When you initially create the VM, there are a number of options available under the cloud API scope section. Select the storage permission to give your VM access to cloud storage.

Now the VM has access to storage, you can use the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) command to access information directly from the cloud storage bucket using the name of the storage bucket.

You will also be able to extend the access of the storage bucket to colleagues should you wish by doing the above. Access permissions for the project can be controlled via IAM section of google cloud.